# I want to show paragraph content for 5 minutes when button clicked even when on page refresh in java code using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var limit = 5 * 60 * 1000

jQuery('#button').click(function() {

  var timer = setTimeout(disableMyButton, limit);

});

function disableMyButton() {
  $("#statusMsg").text("Disabling before page refresh");
  localStorage.setItem("isMyButtonDisabled", "true");
}

if (localStorage.getItem("isMyButtonDisabled") == "true") {
  $("#statusMsg").text("Disabling after page refresh");
  $('#employeeForm_OOBPIN').prop('disabled', true);
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete

Comment: Move timer outside the click handler or make the function anonymous. `var timer` is only available to the click handler

Comment: Instead of storing "true" to the local storage, store the date when to hide/remove the content. Then on page load, read the time, and if it's in the future, start a timeout, otherwise just hide/remove the content.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages. Please don't tag Java when you mean JavaScript.